# how call method logged_in in rails from model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

actually i use restful-authentication but ai need call method logged_in from MODEL (no controller) distinct of user.

can you help me...

example:

**modelx.rb**

```
def price
    if logged_in?
        @product.price = current_user.prices
    else
        @product.price = 0
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a better design to pass that information in from where you are calling the method.

```
def price(logged_in = false)
  if logged_in
    @product.price = current_user.prices
  else
    @product.price = 0
  end
end
```

Calling it from the controller or view:

```
@modelx.price(logged_in?)
```